# How to zip multiple files from different folders and store that zip files in one folder using java

Tags: java, zip

How to Zip multiple files from two different folders and store it in any of these two folder using java

Comment: Have you even tried anything? You obviously haven't done any research about it since its all over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402011/lgap) had a similar question, check it out: [Zipping a folder which contains subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961087/zipping-a-folder-which-contains-subfolders)

The answer to their question **(Posted by [dogbane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412/dogbane))** could answer yours, it is as follows:

> You need to check if the file is a directory because you can't pass
>   directories to the zip method.
>
> Take a look at [this page](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14049) which shows how you can recursively zip
>   a given directory.