# Java - Combining 2 zipping methods into one

Tags: java

I have based a code from this thread (third post by Bane)
[Zipping a folder which contains subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961087/zipping-a-folder-which-contains-subfolders)

And if we observe the code, it is actually split to two because it was called on the main method. What I did with my code is that I turned the main method code into a normal method which will be accepting the zip file's future file name as a parameter:

```
public void (String myZipFileName) {
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\vebrpav\\" + myZipFileName);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
addDirToZipArchive(zos, new File("C:\\Users\\vebrpav\\Downloads\\"), null);
zos.flush();
fos.flush();
zos.close();
fos.close();
}
```

And I realized later on that I want the 2 methods to be merged in one with the method only accepting the myZipFileName as a parameter.

I tried revising the code but I got confused at the if statement where if the file is a directory.

```
    if (fileToZip.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("+" + zipEntryName);
    for (File file : fileToZip.listFiles()) {
        addDirToZipArchive(zos, file, zipEntryName);
    }
```

How am I supposed to merge these two methods if my code will only accept my zip file's name as a parameter? Is this possible?

Comment: If the method only accepts one discrete argument, then why does it need an argument in the first place?

Comment: Why would you want to merge them? And no, the second method is a recursive method that doesn’t need the file name but it does need its other arguments.

Comment: It is splited because the second method is recursive. Is possible use recursion in only one method in your case but the implementation will have a strange signature and confusing implementation. You can rewrite it using only loops also.