# How to zip folder with subfolders and files in Java

Tags: java

listFiles method:

```
  public File[] listFiles (String path) {
    File[] files = Paths.get(path).toFile().listFiles();

    if (files.length == 0)
        System.out.println("Brak plikow");

    List<Integer> listElements = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Lista plikow mozliwych do spakowania: ");
    for (int i=0; i< files.length; i++)
        System.out.println(i+1 + ": " + files[i]);

    System.out.println("Podaj pliki, ktore chcesz spakowac: ");
    while(true) {
        try {
            int nextEl = scan.nextInt();
            if (nextEl >= 1 && nextEl <= files.length)
                listElements.add(nextEl);
            else
                break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }



    File[] newFiles = new File[listElements.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<listElements.size(); i++)
        newFiles[i] = files[listElements.get(i) -1];

    return newFiles;
```

packingArchive method:

```
public void packingArchive(File[] files, String zipName) {

    try {
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipName));
        zipOut.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                packingArchive(f.listFiles(),  f.getParentFile() + "/" + f.getName());
                System.out.println( f.listFiles());
            }
            else {
                ZipEntry zipE = new ZipEntry(f.getName());
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipE);
                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
                zipOut.write(fileIn.readAllBytes());
                fileIn.close();
                zipOut.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        zipOut.flush();
        zipOut.close();
        System.out.println("Zapisano plik do archiwum ZIP");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
    PackageZip pz = new PackageZip();

    File[] files = pz.listFiles("Client/pliki");
    pz.packingArchive(files, "Archiwum.zip");
```

I'm trying to zip a folder which contains subfolders and files.
I have a class named PackageZip that contains method named packingArchive which takes a File array that contains all files in a current directory, and a String zipName.I also created method named listFiles that take a path and return an array of Files that I choose to zip.

The above code gave me a following Exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Client\pliki\Nowy (Access is denied) at
> java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) at
> java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)    at
> java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:235)
> at
> java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:123)
> at PackageZip.packingArchive(PackageZip.java:51)    at
> PackageZip.packingArchive(PackageZip.java:55)     at
> Main.main(Main.java:22)

I am fresh in Java, could you help me and give some advices?

Comment: You are creating a new zip file each time you recurse into packingArchive, and you give it the name of a file which already exists.

Comment: Try looking at [Zipping a folder which contains subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961087/zipping-a-folder-which-contains-subfolders).