# How to compress files in RAR format in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my project I have a requirement to compress my files using only the **RAR format**.

How can I compress a **File to RAR** format in **Android**?

Comment: you can't, that's a proprietary format. also, you don't want to do that. there are zip and gzip compression classes available.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't use zip because my requirement is that after unzipping I need to get only the individual files directly without a folder containing those files. So only the RAR format was supporting this in Windows.

Comment: You can put files in a zip without a folder. That works on Windows too.

Comment: This has little to do with Android specifically. You will need to find a third-party JAR that offers RAR compression for Java, then work to make sure that JAR works on Android.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The structure that I need to compress is like this: (FolderA, Text1.txt, Text2.txt) and after uncompressing I need to get it in the same way ie; (FolderA, Text1.txt, Text2.txt) without creating a structure like this (CompressedFolderName(FolderA, Text1.txt, Text2.txt)) where CompressedFolderName contains my FolderA, Text1.txt and Text2.txt. So to get it in that way only RAR seemed to be supporting it on Windows.

Comment: that has to do with your unzipper on windows, not with android

Comment: If you use WinRAR to unzip your .zip files on Windows, it'll work just like a .rar file.  It all has to do with the unzipper, not the format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAR is a proprietary format, with a closed algorithm, so you will probably not find any open source Java API for it.

But Zip will do what you want and is widely available and comes with Api in Java.

Comment: The answers in this question might give you a starting point for adapting your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740375/directories-in-a-zip-file-when-using-java-util-zip-zipoutputstream

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used the Zip format only and not RAR.