# Make rar and unrar file in android programming

Tags: android

Can anyone please give me a sample example on crating .rar file and again unrar that file in Android.

I googled it, but did not get proper result.

I got how to make zip and unzip.

Comment: ... and what for? you have **zip**, which is a universally adopted standard...

Comment: I have such requirement, make zip and rar files in my project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530497/how-to-compress-files-in-rar-format-in-android