# How to create a zip file and keep entries for directories?

Tags: java, zip

I would like to create a zip archive from a folder and keep entries for (non-empty) directories.

In the code below, `FileInputStream` throws a `FileNotFoundException` when a directory is passed to `AddToZip`. I have tried to put a condition around the actual writing of bytes but it makes the whole archive invalid. How can I add directory entries to the archive?

```
public static void addToZip(File directoryToZip, File file, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {

    String zipFilePath = file.getCanonicalPath().substring(directoryToZip.getCanonicalPath().length() + 1,file.getCanonicalPath().length());
    System.out.println("Writing '" + zipFilePath + "' to zip file");
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(zipFilePath);
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); // Throws a FileNotFoundException when directory
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }

    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();

}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740375/directories-in-a-zip-file-when-using-java-util-zip-zipoutputstream)?

Comment: @fge : Yes but just adding the entry without writing bytes seems to make the archive invalid

Comment: @fge: After all it worked. I had to add the forward slash to the filepath

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is there in this old post. Please check.

[directories in a zip file when using java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740375/directories-in-a-zip-file-when-using-java-util-zip-zipoutputstream)

Comment: This should be definitely a comment.

Comment: thanks Jack but I am new to stackover flow and still learning the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some utility methods to copy files and directories to a Zip file using the NIO.2 File API (the library is Open Source):

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html#AddZipResourceSample

API: [CopyFileVisitor.copy](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29)

Comment: here is one more example which can be helpful to you. http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/showTutorials.action?tutorialId=Java_ZipUtilities_ZipEmptyDirectory